# Why isn't the tkinter window showing?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to build a student management system while this tkinter window does not show after running following code. Can someone give some advice here? This is public source code from youtube chanel.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Student:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("student management system")
        self.root.geometry("1350*700+0+0")

        title=Label(self.root,text="Student Management System",bd=10,relief=GROOVE,front=("time new roman",40,"bold"),bg="yellow",fg="red")
        title.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

        Manage_Frame=Frame(self.root,bd=4,relief=RIDGE,bg="crimson")
        Manage_Frame.place(x=20,y=70,width=450,height=560)

    #========Massage Frame===============================
        Manage_Frame=Frame(self.root,bd=4,relief=RIDGE,bg="crimson")
        Manage_Frame.place(x=20,y=100,width=450,height=560)

        m_title=Label(Manage_Frame,text="Manage Students",bg="crimson",fg="white",front=("time new roman",30,"bold"))
        m_title.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,pady=10)

        lbl_roll = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Roll No.", bg="crimson", fg="white",front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_roll.grid(row=1, colum=0, pady=10,padx=20,sticky="w")

        txt_roll = Entry(Manage_Frame,front=("time new roman", 15, "bold"),bd=5,relief=GROOVE)
        txt_roll.grid(row=1, colum=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_name = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Name", bg="crimson", fg="white", front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_name.grid(row=1, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_name = Entry(Manage_Frame, front=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_name.grid(row=2, colum=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_Email = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Email", bg="crimson", fg="white", front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_Email.grid(row=1, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_Email = Entry(Manage_Frame, front=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Email.grid(row=3, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_Gender = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Gender", bg="crimson", fg="white", front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_Gender.grid(row=4, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        combo_Gender=ttk.Combobox(Manage_Frame,front=("times new roman",20,"bold"))
        combo_Gender['values']=("Male","Female","other")
        combo_Gender.grid(row=4,colum=1,padx=20,pady=10)

        lbl_Contact = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Contact", bg="crimson", fg="white", front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_Contact.grid(row=5, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_Contact = Entry(Manage_Frame, front=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Contact.grid(row=5, colum=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_DOB = Label(Manage_Frame, text="DOB", bg="crimson", fg="white",front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_DOB.grid(row=6, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_Contact = Entry(Manage_Frame, front=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Contact.grid(row=6, colum=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_address = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Address", bg="crimson", fg="white", front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_address.grid(row=6, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_address = Entry(Manage_Frame, front=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_address.grid(row=6, colum=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

    #=========Button Frame=========

        btn_Frame=Frame(Manage_Frame,bd=4,relief=RIDGE,bg="crimson")
        btn_Frame.place(x=15, y=500, width=420)

        Addbtn = Button(btn_Frame,text="add",width=10).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        Updatebtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="update", width=10).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        Deletebtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="delete", width=10).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        Clearbtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="clear", width=10).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

    #=========Detail Frame=========
        Detail_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg="crimson")
        Detail_Frame.place(x=500, y=100, width=800, height=580)

        lbl_search = Label(Detail_Frame, text="Search By", bg="crimson", fg="white", front=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_search.grid(row=0, colum=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        combo_search = ttk.Combobox(Manage_Frame,width=10,front=("times new roman", 13, "bold"),state="readonly")
        combo_search['values'] = ("Roll", "Name", "contact")
        combo_search.grid(row=0, colum=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        txt_Search = Entry(Manage_Frame,width=15, front=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Search.grid(row=6, colum=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        searchbtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="Search", width=10).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
        showallbtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="Show All", width=10).grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

    #=========Table Frame=========
        Table_Frame = Frame(Detail_Frame, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg="crimson")
        Table_Frame.place(x=10, y=70, width=760, height=500)

        scroll_x=Scrollbar(Table_Frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scroll_y = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        Student_table=ttk.Treeview(Table_Frame,columns=("roll","name","email","gender","contact","dob","Address"),xscollcommand=scroll_x.set,yscollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scroll_x.config(command=Student_table.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=Student_table.xview)
        Student_table.heading("roll",text="Roll")
        Student_table.heading("name", text="Name")
        Student_table.heading("email", text="Email")
        Student_table.heading("gender", text="Gender")
        Student_table.heading("Contact", text="Contact")
        Student_table.heading("D.O.B", text="D.O.B")
        Student_table.heading("Address", text="Address")
        Student_table['show']='headings'
        Student_table.pack()

root=Tk()
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  You need to create an instance of `Student` class and call `root.mainloop()`.  Better search for some tkinter tutorials for beginners on the Internet before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your Student object and pass root to it. Add this to the end of your code for it to run:

```
app=Student(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Your current code as is includes a lot of syntax errors that need to be fixed before running. The following should run, albeit with some visual errors:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Student:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("student management system")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700")

        title=Label(self.root,text="Student Management System",bd=10,relief=GROOVE,font=("time new roman",40,"bold"),bg="yellow",fg="red")
        title.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

        Manage_Frame=Frame(self.root,bd=4,relief=RIDGE,bg="crimson")
        Manage_Frame.place(x=20,y=70,width=450,height=560)

    #========Massage Frame===============================
        Manage_Frame=Frame(self.root,bd=4,relief=RIDGE,bg="crimson")
        Manage_Frame.place(x=20,y=100,width=450,height=560)

        m_title=Label(Manage_Frame,text="Manage Students",bg="crimson",fg="white",font=("time new roman",30,"bold"))
        m_title.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,pady=10)

        lbl_roll = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Roll No.", bg="crimson", fg="white",font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_roll.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10,padx=20,sticky="w")

        txt_roll = Entry(Manage_Frame,font=("time new roman", 15, "bold"),bd=5,relief=GROOVE)
        txt_roll.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_name = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Name", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_name.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_name = Entry(Manage_Frame, font=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_name.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_Email = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Email", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_Email.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_Email = Entry(Manage_Frame, font=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Email.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_Gender = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Gender", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_Gender.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        combo_Gender=ttk.Combobox(Manage_Frame,font=("times new roman",20,"bold"))
        combo_Gender['values']=("Male","Female","other")
        combo_Gender.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=20,pady=10)

        lbl_Contact = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Contact", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_Contact.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_Contact = Entry(Manage_Frame, font=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Contact.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_DOB = Label(Manage_Frame, text="DOB", bg="crimson", fg="white",font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_DOB.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_Contact = Entry(Manage_Frame, font=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Contact.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        lbl_address = Label(Manage_Frame, text="Address", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_address.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        txt_address = Entry(Manage_Frame, font=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_address.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

    #=========Button Frame=========

        btn_Frame=Frame(Manage_Frame,bd=4,relief=RIDGE,bg="crimson")
        btn_Frame.place(x=15, y=500, width=420)

        Addbtn = Button(btn_Frame,text="add",width=10).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        Updatebtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="update", width=10).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        Deletebtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="delete", width=10).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        Clearbtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="clear", width=10).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

    #=========Detail Frame=========
        Detail_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg="crimson")
        Detail_Frame.place(x=500, y=100, width=800, height=580)

        lbl_search = Label(Detail_Frame, text="Search By", bg="crimson", fg="white", font=("time new roman", 20, "bold"))
        lbl_search.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        combo_search = ttk.Combobox(Manage_Frame,width=10,font=("times new roman", 13, "bold"),state="readonly")
        combo_search['values'] = ("Roll", "Name", "contact")
        combo_search.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)

        txt_Search = Entry(Manage_Frame,width=15, font=("time new roman", 15, "bold"), bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
        txt_Search.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="w")

        searchbtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="Search", width=10).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
        showallbtn = Button(btn_Frame, text="Show All", width=10).grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

    #=========Table Frame=========
        Table_Frame = Frame(Detail_Frame, bd=4, relief=RIDGE, bg="crimson")
        Table_Frame.place(x=10, y=70, width=760, height=500)

        scroll_x=Scrollbar(Table_Frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scroll_y = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        Student_table=ttk.Treeview(Table_Frame,columns=("roll","name","email","gender","contact","dob","Address"),xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set,yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scroll_x.config(command=Student_table.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=Student_table.xview)
        Student_table.heading("roll",text="Roll")
        Student_table.heading("name", text="Name")
        Student_table.heading("email", text="Email")
        Student_table.heading("gender", text="Gender")
        Student_table.heading("contact", text="Contact")
        Student_table.heading("dob", text="D.O.B")
        Student_table.heading("Address", text="Address")
        Student_table['show']='headings'
        Student_table.pack()

root=Tk()
app=Student(root)
root.mainloop()
```